# Class scrbook Error: undefined old font command `\sl'. \end{thebibliography}

Tags: bibtex, scrbook

What could be the reason for the next latex error:

```
Class scrbook Error: undefined old font command `\sl'. \end{thebibliography}
```

I can affirm that the problem comes from a citation, but actually I couldn't know more.

Could anyone please provide me information on what is that error, ideas about how to fix it ?? all suggestions are welcome.

Regards,

Comment: You are using a bibliography style that uses font commands that are obsolete for over 25 years. Use enabledeprecatedfontcommands as global option.

Comment: And maybe think about switching to a more modern approach like biblatex with biber.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: dear @Mico, I am actually using scrbook document class and the standard alpha style for bibliography.

Comment: Dear @Johannes_B, I am using alpha style do you think its the reason for this problem ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Use the above mentioned option.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376545/37907

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: @Johannes_B Actually I just resolved the problem, I don't know but I just removed apalike and everything was okay without any errors or warnings. Otherwise srcbook class with alpha bibstyle work well without any additional options. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by removing apalike package. The bibstyle alpha worked well with srcbook class used font, my bibliography is printed normally without any additional options. I hope that this can help in resolving future stackexchangers problems.

Comment: With the information given in the question, nobody could have guessed you are using apalike. You did not give a minimal working example.